# How to locally unit test python 3 app engine application?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have testbed setup locally to test python2.7 based app engine application. As part of the python3 migration activity, I am wondering how do I setup the app engine testbed. It seems I can't use my existing python2.7 testbed because of the changes in app engine libraries. Can anybody help me in setting it up?

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find any relevant doc for the new AppEngine 3 environment and the testbed package. According to the documentation in the python docs for AppEngine the testbed package doesn't belong more to the python 3 official libraries for AppEngine.

You can read the content of the package here:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.ext.testbed

Maybe if you isolate your unit tests in a acceptable level, you can exclude the remote resources.