# Does the Python 3 runtime of Google App Engine support unit tests using `google.appengine.ext.testbed`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

When writing for the Python 2.7 runtime, it was possible to write unit tests that ran directly from a virtual environment with the SDK installed with access to local emulators for most of the available runtime environment. In order for that to work, one would need to import:

```py
from google.appengine.ext import testbed
```

And then, from within the TestCase class, you could use

```py
def setUp(self):
    self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()
    self.testbed.activate()
    self.testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub()
    self.testbed.init_memcache_stub()
    self.testbed.init_taskqueue_stub()
```

to have local emulators for the desired services.

This doesn't seem possible (or, at least, obvious) from the Python 3 runtime docs. I couldn't find any tests in the examples provided that didn't go through the HTTP interfaces (making it much harder to test individual components).

Answer (score 1):

So, I've searched on this and it looks like there are like a lot of this concerns all over stack overflow about the unit testing... it looks like it is not possible now as it is posted in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58239037/how-to-locally-unit-test-python-3-app-engine-application), apparently the package got removed, you can check this at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.ext.testbed) as the other post mentioned.